# Kubernetes - Benefit of Reducing pods

Tags: optimization, kubernetes, cloud, cluster-computing, kubernetes-pod

What would be the main **benefits** of reducing the number of replicas:

```
  deployment:    
    replicaCount: 100       
    maxReplicaCount: 1000      
    rollingUpdate:      
      maxSurge: 150
```

Throughput (`rpm`) is not that big and I'm planning to reduce replica count.

Answer (score 0):

in my case who's in dev stage, you can save up some resource for your prioritized services or spin up new deployment for new features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain spin up new deployment part?

Comment: basically just create a new kubernetes deployment kind, nothing else